# How to develop tridion mobile site

Tags: tridion

My company want me to develop static mobile site in tridion using java, jsp, html and css. Please help me what are steps follow to develop a mobile site in tridion.

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 main things to consider while developing a mobile site in Tridion:

1. Content / Template Blueprint Structure - Will your mobile site be a
   1:1 copy of the content on the main site?  Or a subset of content
   specific to certain actions / sections the mobile visitor will
   likely use?  I think the subsite approach is best for websites where
   most users register for a flight, buy a product, or login to use a
   web app.  The subsite could also include a link to the main site. 
   The subsite would have its own set of templates, components, and
   pages but re-use the schemas.
2. CSS/HTML - Rendering the site well on a mobile device is a game of writing good, clean HTML and CSS targeted to mobile browsers.  This is easily done in Tridion with new templates for a subsite approach.  But, if you decide to offer all the same content as the main site but with a mobile friendly CSS then you have a more serious effort to re-write your existing CSS / HTML and use a responsive design.  This is a much bigger effort than a subsite - but your website design would be 'future proof' and work with most mobile browsers for the next few years.

I hope this helps.  This is a common question and Tridion's Blueprint technology can help you maximize re-use of schemas, templates, and content across different channels.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend reading this: https://www.sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2011/mobile_websites.aspx

I think this would be a good starting point for you.